# Can not modify DataFrame using a simple condition statement. But works when using a static number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to change the series of a pandas DataFrame object using the iterrows() function. The DataFrame is full of random floats. Below is a sample of both pieces of code:

This one works:

```
for index,row in other_copy.iterrows()
    other_copy.loc[index] = (other_copy.loc[index] > 30)
```

But this one doesn't:

```
for index,row in other_copy.iterrows():
   top_3 = other_copy.loc[index].nlargest(3)
   minimum = min(top_3)
   other_copy.loc[index] = (other_copy.loc[index] > minimum)
```

The first one modifies the DataFrame, True and False accordingly. However, the second one gives me the below error:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-116-11f6c908f54a> in <module>()
      1 for index,row in other_copy.iterrows():
----> 2     top_3 = other_copy.loc[index].nlargest(3)
      3     minimum = min(top_3)
      4     other_copy.loc[index] = (other_copy.loc[index] > minimum)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
nlargest(self, n, keep)    2061         dtype: float64    2062        
"""
-> 2063         return algorithms.SelectNSeries(self, n=n, keep=keep).nlargest()    2064     2065     def nsmallest(self, n=5,
keep='first'):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in
nlargest(self)
    915 
    916     def nlargest(self):
--> 917         return self.compute('nlargest')
    918 
    919     def nsmallest(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in
compute(self, method)
    952             raise TypeError("Cannot use method '{method}' with "
    953                             "dtype {dtype}".format(method=method,
--> 954                                                    dtype=dtype))
    955 
    956         if n <= 0:

TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object
```

Am I missing something simple here? The minimum variable is just a float and the comparison should go through. I even tried by using

```
int(minimum)
```

but it still gives me the same error. Also I'm able to use:

```
print(other_copy.loc[index] > minimum)
```

and this works as well to print the correct response. Any ideas why this might be happening? Sorry if this is something simple.

Comment: `.nlargest()` is used on a DataFrame/Column, not on an individual row.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do with your function? Check if the index is larger/smaller then the third largest index number?

Comment: Yes, each row has a bunch of values and I'm getting the 3rd largest value of each row and everything lower than it will be marked as False. The top 3 largest values will then be marked as True. In other words it's going row by row in the DataFrame and changing the values from floats to True and False depending on if they satisfy the condition.

Comment: Again, it works fine when I put a normal number in the condition rather than the 'minimum' variable. The 'minimum' variable in the end is just a normal number as well. It just doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `minimum`, it's the code that sets `minimum`. When you slice out your row, it turns into a series which has a dtype `object` (because there are mixed dtypes in your columns the `object` dtype is the only one that's compatible with all of them)

When you try to run `.nlargest()` on this row slice, it clearly tells you the problem: `TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object` You should therefore cast your series to a numeric.

```
import pandas as pd

for index,row in other_copy.iterrows():
   top_3 = pd.to_numeric(other_copy.loc[index], errors = 'coerce').nlargest(3)
   minimum = min(top_3)
   other_copy.loc[index] = (other_copy.loc[index] > minimum)
```

This may cause another error if there are no entries that can be cast to numerics in the row, and it probably will fail if you try to do an unsafe comparison (like `'str'` > `'float'`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the issue now, thank you for clarifying the reason. :)